# How to write fitnesse code for a method which accepts 2 parameters

Tags: fitnesse, fixture, fitnesse-slim

I'm newbie to fitnesse and trying to run a simple calculator class which has "add" method accepting 2 parameters and returning the result. Can anyone help me to write the firnesse code for this, my method is as below

```
public int add(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to write a test that checks whether add returns the right result for various values of a and b? What test framework are you using Fit or Slim?

Comment: yes, correct, i want to chk if add return correct rsults for diff values of a and b. I'm using Fit framework

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to get a table like:

```
|AddFixtureTest |
|left|right|sum?|
|1   |1    |2   |
|2   |4    |6   |
```

This requires a java class like:

```
import fit.ColumnFixture;

public class AddFixtureTest extends ColumnFixture {
    public int left;
    public int right;

    public int sum(){
        return add(left, right);
    }
    private int add(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

See http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FixtureGallery.BasicFitFixtures.ColumnFixture

Answer (score 1):

I assume Slim is fine by you and I'm gonna use script table for this (more out of habit):

```
|script| <class name> |
|add;| <variable1> | <variable2> |
```

As simple as that. And, make sure you are using the right libraries and pointing to the location of the where the **class** file is.

Example:

```
|import|
fitnesse.slim.test |
```

If you are interested in knowing why I have placed a semi-colon after "add", and how script table works, please go through this:

http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ScriptTable

Answer (score 0):

You can get the FitNesse tutorial [there](https://github.com/imanushin/NetRunner/wiki/Net-Runner-tutorial) for .Net code. I tried to describe how to use FitNesse for different types of testing.
If you want to check two parameters on the output you can do the following:

- Return IEnumerable implementation with classes, which contains get
  and set properties (see [here](https://github.com/imanushin/NetRunner/wiki/Collection-result)). NetRunner will use get properties
  if it can, otherwise it will use set properties. As a result, it will
  set all available data first and then compare items left.
- You can use [out parameters](https://github.com/imanushin/NetRunner/wiki/Out-paremeters) in the tests, so you can return several different values and check them

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

```
|script:<classPackage>.<ClassName>|
|check|add;|8|8|16|
```

First tell the script to navigate to the correct class. In the next line you have to call either a method or a constructor. You can call the method by it's name (or fancy smansy digibetic words that vaguely match) and tack on a semicolon. But anything put into the pipe-blocks after that will be interpreted as parameters for that method. So how do you put the expected output?
The trick is to tell the FitNesse engine you need a result, with the keyword 'check'.
This will make the final pipe-block be the field for the expected result, in this case 16.

[Here is a picture of the java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aElrW.png)

[Here is a picture of the text input and the FitNesse sceen result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALQY4.jpg)